# sass argument `$n` of `nth($list, $n)` must be a number

Tags: sass

In the sass list, can the index value be represented by a variable?

```
$colors:#111 #222 #333 #444;
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  :nth-child(#{$i}):after{
      background: nth($colors, #{$i});
   }
}
```

in sass `nth(colors,index)`, `index` can use variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. You just have some issues with your syntax, and you haven't defined nth child of 'what'.  This example shows how you could apply your sass to list items. This also uses the length of the array to determine the number of loops versus manually setting that to 4 making your code a little more future proof.

```
$colors: #111 #222 #333 #444;
  @for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
    background: nth($colors, $i);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggwa3bv1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map instead, https://jsfiddle.net/uyzk15d6/

```
$colors: (
    red: 1,
    green: 2,
    blue: 3,
    orange: 4
);

@each $color, $child in $colors {
    li:nth-child(#{$child}n) {
      background: $color;
   }
}
```